# How to Add the Text in Embed Text Field

Tags: flash

I know this simple question. But i not much experience in Flash AS2.O. 
I have one empty dynamic text file in the instance name "my_text". I have set the Embed option in that file. Now I need to add the text to that file through AS2.0.

I have tried both the code is not working.

my_text.htmlText  =  "My Name is Balaganesh K"; 
                  (or) 
  my_text.text  = "My Name is Balaganesh K";

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way ?

```
 _root.my_text="My name is Balaganesh";
```

Comment: I tried 
 -root.my_text.text = "Balaganesh" AND
 -root.my_text = "Balaganesh"

both is not working?

Comment: its not - (hyphen) , it is _ (underscore)